# Executing administration tasks on linux from windows server 2008

Tags: windows, linux, powershell, admin

What toolkits are out there that will allow me to do the following things from a windows 2008 server to a linux server? In other words I have a windows 2008 server that performs admin tasks using powershell against other windows servers on the domain using WMI and UNC shares. Soon I will be required to do the same automated tasks on linux based servers. I want to have a single windows based server that can perform these admin tasks against both linux and windows using one technology, or two if I must, but definitely only want to have to maintain a single windows based server for this.

Access remote hard drive shares e.g. Currently use c$, d$, ... hidden share on windows based systems
Execute commands remotely. e.g. Currently use WMI remote execution on windows based systems
Start, pause, stop Tomcat/Apache web servers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of installing cygwin and all its dependencies, you can use just PLink.exe with this script : Invoke-SSH (http://www.zerrouki.com/invoke-ssh/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org/). It works nicely for administering Unix hosts, and also claims to support Windows. You might need some basic [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) tools installed, however.